# TTNavigator keeps going to the wildcard page. Any idea what happens?

Tags: iphone, three20

My iPhone TTNavigator keeps loading the wildcard page even though the URL (i.e. 'tt://root') is valid

```
@synthesize navigator;

// 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    [navigator setWindow:window];

    // Routing Table
    TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
    [map from:@"tt://root" toViewController:[MainTabBarController class]];
    [map from:@"tt://newsfeed" toViewController:[NewsFeedViewController class]];

    // First stop
    if (![navigator restoreViewControllers]) {
        [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://root"]];
    }
}
```

When I comment out the wildcard section that redirects to the WebView, it will load the "tt://root" when the app starts.

Any idea what I'm missing out?

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restoreViewControllers message restores cached view controllers. It may be that the wildcard mapping is the last view you navigated to and is therefore on top of the cached navigation stack.

I would first try deleting the app from the simulator/device, cleaning the project, rebuilding, and deploying onto the simulator/device.